# ¿Cómo hago que un programa en tkinter genere la animación de un que se presiona el botón sin que se presione el botón?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una especie de juego de memoria en tkinter y necesito que el programa genere la animación de un botón al presionarse; pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, aquí está el codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
import random, time
root = Tk()
root.title('Colors')
root.resizable(0, 0)
puntos = 0
puntos_maximos = 0

def borrar():
    numero = random.randrange(0,4)
    if numero == 1:
        boton_rojo.grid_forget()
    if numero == 2:
        boton_amarrilo.grid_forget()
    if numero == 3:
        boton_azul.grid_forget()
    if numero == 4:
        boton_verde.grid_forget()
    return numero


def iniciar():
    boton_iniciar.grid_forget()
    for i in range(0, puntos + 5):
        borrar()

texto1 = Label(root, text='puntaje: ' + str(puntos)).grid(row=2, column=0)
texto2 = Label(root, text='puntaje maxímo: ' + str(puntos_maximos)).grid(row=2, column=1)

boton_rojo = Button(root, text='', bg='red', width=15, height=4, cursor='hand2')
boton_rojo.grid(row=0, column=0)
boton_azul = Button(root, text='', bg='blue', width=15, height=4, cursor='hand2')
boton_azul.grid(row=1, column=0)
boton_amarrilo = Button(root, text='', bg='yellow', width=15, height=4, cursor='hand2')
boton_amarrilo.grid(row=0, column=1)
boton_verde = Button(root, text='', bg='green', width=15, height=4, cursor='hand2')
boton_verde.grid(row=1, column=1)

boton_iniciar = Button(root, text='Iniciar juego', width=30, command=iniciar)
boton_iniciar.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)



root.mainloop()
```

Mi idea es que se presione el botón para así darle el patron al usuario que luego ha de introducir con los botones de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes conseguir con este código (aunque realmente no se presiona el botón)

```
from tkinter import *
import random, time
root = Tk()
root.title('Colors')
root.resizable(0, 0)
puntos = 0
puntos_maximos = 0

class TimeManager:
    def __init__(self, function):
        # Guarda la función
        self.function = function

        # Crea el generador
        self.generator = function()

    def next(self):
        # Obtiene el siguiente valor del generador.
        # Si el generador se agotó, le indicamos que devuelva None.
        time = next(self.generator, None)

        if(time is None):
            # Si el generador se agotó, lo volvemos a iniciar.
            self.generator = self.function()
        else:
            # En caso contrario, mandamos a que este método se llame dentro del tiempo devuelto por el generador.
            root.after(time, self.next)

def mostrar_patron():
    for i in range(0, puntos + 5):
        # Elegimos al azar el botón a afectar.
        boton = random.choice((boton_rojo, boton_azul, boton_amarrilo, boton_verde))

        # Guardamos el relief original en una variable
        boton_relief = boton["relief"]
        # Le damos un nuevo valor al relief.
        boton["relief"] = "sunken"

        yield 500
        
        # le devolvemos su valor original.
        boton["relief"] = boton_relief

        yield 500

texto1 = Label(root, text='puntaje: ' + str(puntos)).grid(row=2, column=0)
texto2 = Label(root, text='puntaje maxímo: ' + str(puntos_maximos)).grid(row=2, column=1)

boton_rojo = Button(root, text='', bg='red', width=15, height=4, cursor='hand2')
boton_rojo.grid(row=0, column=0)
boton_azul = Button(root, text='', bg='blue', width=15, height=4, cursor='hand2')
boton_azul.grid(row=1, column=0)
boton_amarrilo = Button(root, text='', bg='yellow', width=15, height=4, cursor='hand2')
boton_amarrilo.grid(row=0, column=1)
boton_verde = Button(root, text='', bg='green', width=15, height=4, cursor='hand2')
boton_verde.grid(row=1, column=1)

boton_iniciar = Button(root, text='Iniciar juego', width=30, command=TimeManager(mostrar_patron).next)
boton_iniciar.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

La idea es crear una función generadora que vaya devolviendo el tiempo de espera antes de avanzar a la siguiente parte. Usando la ayuda de una clase llamada TimeManager, logramos entonces que la función genere un valor, se "pause" y siga dentro de un determinado tiempo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias